# Regular expression for patterns in CodeIgniter URIs

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have another question asked her on Stack Overflow and was suggested to use regular expressions instead of PHP code. Unfortunately I don’t know regexp, and have tried many times in the past and now to understand it without success. So hopefully, if I ask nicely, someone here could help. I would be very grateful.

What I’m trying to achieve is so route different URI requests to different places, 4 to be specific. What would be a proper reg exp to match the following:

- *`year`* (example: `2010`)
- *`year-month`* (example: `2010-nov`) (the month represented by 3 chars)
- *`year-month-day`* (example: `2010-nov-10`)
- *`year-month-day-string`* (example: `2010-nov-10-blog-post-title-here`)

I’m coding in PHP and using the CodeIgniter framework.

Regards,
Jason

Comment: Just one hint: You would be off easier if your months were numbers instead of their abbreviations.

Comment: i hear you. i just need them to be 3 chars though, I will validate it at the next stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are validating later. you can go really generic:

`([0-9]{4})-([a-z]{3})-([0-9]{1,2})-([\w*](-?[\w*])*)`

4 digits year, a hyphen, a 3 char lowercase word, a hyphen, two digits, at least one word, (optional hyphen and another word repeated as needed.)

Comment: fantastic! thats exactly whats needed. all works :) thanks Hyposaurus!

Answer (score 1):

- Year is `(19|20)\d\d`.
- Year-month is `(19|20)\d\d\-[a-z]{3}`
- Year-month-day is `(19|20)\d\d\-[a-z]{3}\-[1-3][0-9]`
- Year-month-day-string is `(19|20)\d\d\-[a-z]{3}\-[1-3][0-9]\-[a-z\-]*`

Correct me if I'm wrong, please. Also note that there is no validation for month names or dates that don't really exist.

Comment: thanks,i guess i should have just put it: 4digits dash 3chars dash 2digits dash string

Comment: That's what it boils down to ;)